# ruby delayed_job - stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, debugging, delayed-job

I am getting regular stack level too deep errors when running from delayed job.

I get this similar error is lots of places in delayed job, but when I run the same code line by line in the console it works fine....

```
Mon Dec 24 2012 01:21:39 stack level too deep
Mon Dec 24 2012 01:21:39 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:157
:in `emit'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:171
:in `emit_w'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:176
:in `emit_n'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:244
:in `strftime'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:218
:in `gsub'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:218
:in `strftime'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb:58
:in `to_s'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:61
:in `quoted_date'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:29
:in `quote'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:236
:in `quote'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2392
:in `quote_bound_value'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2352
:in `replace_bind_variables'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2352
:in `gsub'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2352
:in `replace_bind_variables'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2320
:in `sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2231
:in `sanitize_sql'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1494
:in `merge_conditions'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1492
:in `each'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1492
:in `merge_conditions'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1804
:in `add_conditions!'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1687
:in `construct_finder_sql'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1548
:in `find_every'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1505
:in `find_initial'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:613
:in `find'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/app/models/api_call.rb:20
:in `log'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/lib/twitter_logger.rb:258
:in `log_to_db'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/lib/twitter_logger.rb:138
:in `old_user_timeline'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/lib/twitter_logger.rb:130
:in `user_timeline'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/lib/influencer_helper.rb:1349
:in `safely_get_user_timeline'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/lib/twitter_helper.rb:711
:in `store_followers_tweets'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/lib/delayed_store_follower_tweets.rb:30
:in `perform'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:215
:in `invoke_job'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:93
:in `run_with_lock'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67
:in `timeout'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:93
:in `run_with_lock'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308
:in `realtime'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:92
:in `run_with_lock'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:153
:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:152
:in `each'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:152
:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:199
:in `work_off'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:198
:in `times'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/job.rb:198
:in `work_off'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:28
:in `start'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308
:in `realtime'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:27
:in `start'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:24
:in `loop'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:24
:in `start'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:68
:in `run'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:46
:in `daemonize'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:249
:in `call'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:249
:in `start_proc'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:197
:in `call'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:197
:in `call_as_daemon'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:253
:in `start_proc'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:293
:in `start'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70
:in `run'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons.rb:195
:in `run_proc'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109
:in `call'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109
:in `catch_exceptions'/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons.rb:194
:in `run_proc'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:45
:in `daemonize'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:43
:in `times'/home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20121130183323/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:43
:in `daemonize'script/delayed_job:5
```

The code is too much to include in this forum.

So my questions to be clear are:

1.)After research I as suspecting that I just dont have enough stack space. I saw I can up it using ulimit, but I dont know how to get this ulimit to delayed job, I upped ulimit in my shell (.bashrc) but that didnt seem to help. Can anyone confirm that I am just out of stack space and how to fix? (here is where I got this idea: http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/5-ruby-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)

2.) If its not ulimit, what could it be, how can I debug this....I dont see any recursion or looping in this stack.

Comment: And what is that line of code that runs fine in the console?

Comment: You're asking us to reconstruct your program from the stack trace and, without supplying us a summary of the code you're using, we can't help much.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly legitimate question, and is very clear, there is no need for code to be shown here. This is unfair that you guys closed it, I see tons of similar questions with no answers, this is a very valid question on how rubys stack system works with ulimit.

Comment: ok, I finally was able to get an SA to up my stack limit, this was the problem, ulimit -S, he added to limts.conf *                hard    stack           65536
*                soft    stack           65536  and the problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the stack space won't fix your problem if you have some kind of infinite loop.

I had a similar stack level too deep problem related to delayed_job last week. It turned out to be a known issue of sorts and in my case related to the psych gem (used for YAML serialisation). When delayed job queues a job it serialises the given object to YAML and stores it in the database and I was getting a stack overflow at that point.

Your issue could have a quite different underlying cause (its impossible to tell from the stack trace) but it might be worth checking out https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/349

For me the solution was in the comment: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/349#issuecomment-5391754 (i.e. add the encode_with method to the class of the object that is being serialised.)

Comment: Thanks Steve, thats why I included the stack, I dont think I have an infinite loop here, so this is the first I have seen this error without the loop. Was hoping to learn more about ulimit and ruby stack...